# Programmatically Re-Running SWF Workflows

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-swf

We have a few thousand SWF workflows that have failed over the past year due to various activity bugs. Because the bugs were long-lived, all activity retries failed and the workflows were closed. I want to re-run all of those failed workflows, picking up at the activity that was last executed (and failed). A basic workflow retrigger.

The SWF console has a [Re-Run](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazonswf/latest/developerguide/swf-dg-console-manage-workflow-executions.html) command, but it only lets you select twenty-five workflows at a time, far fewer than the thousands I need.

I could use the CLI [`start-workflow-execution`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/swf/start-workflow-execution.html) command (or analogous API call), but I can't figure out where to get the most recent workflow input the way the Console's 'Re-Run' operation does. I can get the most recent workflow input from [`get-workflow-execution-history`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/swf/get-workflow-execution-history.html), but that requires that I know the most recent `runId` and I can't find any way to get that.

To summarize:

1. The only way I can think to programmatically re-run SWF workflows is: for each failed workflow, magically grab its most recent `runId`, then grab its most recent workflow input via [`get-workflow-execution-history`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/swf/get-workflow-execution-history.html), then restart it using that input via [`start-workflow-execution`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/swf/start-workflow-execution.html). Is there a better way?
2. If the answer to #1 is "There is no better way," then how can I find the most recent `runId` for a particular `workflowId`?

(The fact that I can't find any documentation or discussion on such retriggers makes me worry that I am approaching this the wrong way, so I welcome feedback setting me straight.)

**UPDATE:** Higher level question: What is the right way to handle workflows that terminated due to error conditions that outlasted all retries? The fact that it is so difficult to retrigger SWF workflows makes me think I am misunderstanding the SWF paradigm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that you can do it in this manner. The max workflow history retention is 90 days, so even if you go down the path of getting the workflow execution history you will be able to restart failed workflows for last 90 days
Also aws has an account level restriction on the number and rate at which you can make swf api calls, so once you start making the calls in loop to get history and start workflow you reach this level too soon and start getting exception. 
Better way to approach this is to look at the point where the workflow execution was started from and re run the failed executions again by passing in the same input.

Comment: Your suggestion sounds identical to what I suggested: restart the failed workflow, passing in the same input from when the workflow was previously started. Am I missing something? (The account-level rate limiting is a good nuisance to call out, but I can work around that.)

Comment: No. If you have the list of failed workflows and the input they were started with, then just go ahead and run them again.

Comment: With the giant asterisk that I can't use this approach for anything over 90 days.

Comment: In our company we heavily use swf and we have all the details of the inputs and failures for each workflow executions in our logs. So we don't go to workflow console to get list of failed executions but just our log files.

Answer (score 3):

1. It sounds reasonable. Note that re-executing workflow doesn't restart it from the last failed activity but from the beginning (history is empty).
2. You can use [ListClosedWorkflowExecutions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazonswf/latest/apireference/API_ListClosedWorkflowExecutions.html) to get the most recent `runId`. Note that it supports `workflowId` as a filter parameter.

> UPDATE: Higher level question: What is the right way to handle workflows that terminated due to error conditions that outlasted all retries?

SWF has everything to retry workflow from the point it failed as the whole workflow execution history is preserved. Unfortunately, AWS Flow Framework out of the box doesn't perform state restoration from the previous run. But it is not an inherent limitation and this feature could be added.

> UPDATE 2:

[Temporal Workflow](https://www.temporal.io/) an open source platform, which is based on the same high-level ideas as SWF, does support [reset feature](https://docs.temporal.io/docs/tctl#restart-reset-workflow) that allows restarting workflow from any point by creating a new run with a subset of history.

Comment: Yes, restarting from the very beginning is what I was counting on. (I would love to restart with the same history as the previous workflow, but I don't see any way to do that, and that might have unintended consequences. I will settle for restarting from the beginning.) What do you say to @Rohit's point about the max workflow history retention period?

Comment: If you intend to use it after the retention period you can always dump the history into S3.

Comment: My thought is to have a branch that uses this(^^) approach when daysSinceStarted < 90 and will pull from storage when daysSinceStarted>= 90.

Comment: That would work. I always wanted to incorporate such workflow replay from the previous run history into Flow Framework directly. But never got to it :(.